# bash script MYSQL Running?

Tags: mysql, bash

I have the following script, which when I break it down it works.
However when I run it it tell me that mysql is not running. and starts the mysql server.

When I run `pgrep mysqld | wc -l` it returns 2 but for some reason the script still runs

```
echo "MySQL is down.";
            service mysqld start
```

Here is the original script.

```
#!/bin/bash
UP=$(pgrep mysqld | wc -l);
if [ "$UP" -ne 1 ];
then
        echo "MySQL is down.";
        service mysqld start

else
        echo "All is well.";
fi
```

Comment: ....how often is your mysql crashing that you need this?

Comment: Did you look which lines `pgrep mysqld` returns before counting them?

Answer (score 0):

You are testing the output for 1, but it returns 2 as you wrote. Change -ne condition to -lt.

Anyway, I would use something like this, to see the mysql status, instead of the pgrep: `service mysql status`.